# $\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2}[\sin 2x (1+\cos 3x) ]dx$ . Here $[t]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $t$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2}[\sin 2x (1+\cos 3x) ]dx$ . Here $[t]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: If you plot $sin(2x)(1+cos(3x)$ in that interval you will see $0\leq sin(2x)(1+cos(3x) ,1$ so the floor function of it goes to $zero$  and integral goes to $zero$ too

Comment: Did you try to find the values of $x$ for which $\sin{2x}(1+\cos{3x})$ is an integer?

Comment: How to plot?@Khosrotash

Comment: This function only gives $0$ integer.@RdBasha

Comment: Hii @Khosrotash Can you please say little more on this?

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\sin(2x)(1+\cos(3x)),x\in[0,\pi/2]$$note that $0\leq 2x\leq \pi \to 0\leq \sin(2x)\leq 1\\1+\cos(3x)\geq0\\$
now find max,min of $y=\sin(2x)(1+\cos(3x)) $ on $x\in[0,\pi/2]$ it seems $0\leq y<1 $so $[y]=0$ so $\int_0^{\pi/2}[y]dx\to 0
\\$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/inubfmxu8p

[image]

Comment: It does not seem to be an easy task to find the max and Min value of that function.

Comment: Yes, yo are right. but see the link maybe help you

Answer (score 0):

$I = \int_0^{2\pi} [\sin 2x (1+\cos 3x)] = \int_0^{2\pi} [\sin 2(2\pi - x) (1+\cos 3(2\pi - x))]   =  \int_0^{2\pi} [- \sin 2x (1+\cos 3x)$

$ = -\int_0^{2\pi} [\sin 2x (1+\cos 3x)] - 1$

$\therefore 2I = - \int_0^{2\pi}  dx = -2 \pi  \implies I = - \pi$

Comment: The upper limit of integration is not $2\pi$ !